# How to add a conda environment in jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm try to enable a keras environmnt into jupyter.
Using below commands I added the conda tf environment for Keras :

```
C:>conda create --name tf python=3.5 
C:>activate tf (tf)
C:\Keras\Test>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Next I downloaded Keras-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from : https://repo.continuum.io/archive/)
And successfully installed it.

```
(tf) C:\Keras>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade C:\Keras\Keras-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But then when i type

```
(tf) c:\Keras\Jupyter Notebook
```

.

I would have thought to be able to 'switch' to the tf keras environment.
When starting up the web browser
But all I see in below jupyter page is the python 3 environment which doesn't know of keras. So shouldn't I see a **"tf"** environment here as well?
from both environments i can start the jupyter notebook, but not sure if that should make a difference, both startups dont show tf, am i missing something here?. (in the picture i also show both conda consoles)
[image]

When i try to launch a notebook that makes use of keras.
Then this is the error i see like if it wasnt installed ?. (i'm sure it did though).
[image]

.
However a small test in python ran directly from the console
proves keras is installed and working 
[image]

(but why not in jupyter??)

Answer (score 1):

Well when i was in the (tf) environment made earlier and typed "conda list"
I got a fairly short list of installed packages (just tensorflow) about 26 packages.
Then I noted that jupyter package wasnt in this environment.
Not sure if it should i added it with

```
conda install jupyter
```

After a while (that command added about 8 Gig of python code...) it got installed.
With the message:
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: ok

next i tried

```
(tf) C:\Keras>python -m ipykernel install --user --name tf --display-name "Python3 tensorflow"
```

with a message "Installed kernelspec tf in C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\tf"

> I'm not sure though if this is the proper solution, because would it
>   always be required to add 8Giga just to launch it in a webpage.
>   (seams overkill, but i just dont know if that's normal for conda-jupyter. (while jupyther was allready in the 'plain' python 3
>   enviroment. (or it was available to conda)...not sure i'm thinking
>   perhaps it be better if conda was part of jupyter but maybe its just
>   the otherway around.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally the problem is usually rooted in the fact that the Jupyter kernels are disconnected from Jupyter's shell; in other words, the installer points to a different Python version than is being used in the notebook.

You might first try installing with conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

Otherwise you can try installing from within the notebook itself:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install keras
```

As tempting as it might be... DO NOT DO:

```
# DON'T DO THIS
!pip install keras
```

Comment: i've trying all day (multiple conda installs as well), i (think) I just got it working a minute ago, i'll post it, your welcome to comment it

Comment: posted it curious what you think of it, was it overkill (8gig) or not ?

Comment: Maybe overkill, but if it gets you up and running and you have the memory to spare... why not :)

Comment: Can you run environmenst without adding conda install jupyter ?
I'm new to this so i wasnt sure it would be required. It seams to run now, although now i get all kind of other python errors (python libs are in constant development and some libs are not that stable i noticed, so i joined in on a bug report about matplotlib).

Comment: Kinda tough to plug in without knowing more about the state of your environment. Here is a post I think explains things pretty well: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/ . Maybe this will help you troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Create kernel.json file in  `~/local/share/jupyter/kernels/<YOUR_KERNEL_NAME/`. Take an example for the content from:`/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json`

see: https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html
     https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/kernels.html